# copy all elements of a child

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i want to copy all the elements(/w children) and the values of `info`

```
<root name ="new" code = "22">
   <item>
      <iteminf id = "a22">
        <Name> ram </Name>
        <price> $25 </price>
        <info>
             ....
        </info>
```

i tried this;

```
<xsl:for-each select="info">
     <xsl:for-each select="node()">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

i want this;

```
<info>
      ....
</info>
```

meaning i want the children of info with their elements and values. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please tell us exactly which output format you want (plain text, HTML, XML) and show us the result you want for the input sample you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `<xsl:copy-of select="//info"/>` to copy all `info` elements to the result tree.